# My custom table view wont display data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Github: https://github.com/nneeranjun/Maps.git

I have a CoordinatesCustomCell (TableViewCell) which contains three labels (all of which I have linked properties in the CoordinatesCustomCell.h file). When I create a cell using the reuse identifier in my TableViewController and try to change the text of the labels, they don't appear to be changed when I run the app. Please view my code with the github link above.

DataTableViewController:

```
#import "DataTableViewController.h"
#import "CoordinatesCustomCell.h"
@import Firebase;
FIRDatabaseQuery*data;


@implementation DataTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
return 2;
 }


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 CoordinatesCustomCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CoordinatesCustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.latitude.text = @"Hello";
 cell.longitude.text = @"Hello";

 // Configure the cell...

 return cell;
 }


 @end
```

CoordinatesCustomCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CoordinatesCustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *index;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitude;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitude;

@end
```

Comment: check if Identifier is correct & cell is not nill

Comment: Try by changing property from `weak` to `strong`

Comment: From storyboard, is your prototype cell of type `CoordinatesCustomCell`?

Comment: yes the identifier is correct and the prototype is connected to the CoordinatesCustomCell

Comment: changing it to strong didnt do anything either

Comment: what would happen if it were nil?

Answer (score 1):

You need the first call regiterNib or registerClass for your cell in `viewDidLoad` method

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[CoordinatesCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CoordinatesCustomCell"];
```

or

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CoordinatesCustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CoordinatesCustomCell"];
```

if you use .xib or storyboard for prototype cell
Don't forget set

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: it still gives me an error. I tried your updates also

Comment: sorry I didnt mean to say error. It still doesn't display the values for the labels. There are no errors

Comment: How do you use the prototype cell? In code or in .xib?

Comment: its in my storyboard

Comment: Could you set the Table View Cell identifier in storyboard?

Comment: let check your data source, log it to see it contain data or not.

Comment: Right now i just set the labels to "hello" so its not loading the data yet, but its still not working even with "hello"

Comment: Did you set in storyboard Custom Class for your prototype cell?

Comment: So I download your repo and opened Main.storyboard. You have only one view controller. Is it right for our project? Update it please

Comment: yeah the other view controller is the DataTableViewController. Did you see that?

Comment: No, your storyboard has only one without naming. and other with name LaunchScreen the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114090/discussion-between-nilay-neeranjun-and-isashok).